# Adjust Code to show form on One Line

Tags: html

I need to adjust this code that I need to copy into my .php page so that text all shows on one line.  Right now the 'Subscribe' submit button is on another line from the 'enter email address...' field.  `

```
    <!--Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
    <div id="mc_embed_signup" style="display:none">
    <form action="http://tradingliberation.us6.list-manage2.com/subscribe/post?u=391b0d0328b13e63321867c4b&amp;id=9fce6d2cd6" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <label for="mce-EMAIL">Stay Connected & Take One Step Closer Towards Liberation</label>
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="enter email address..." required><div class="clear">
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </form>
    </div>
    <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Here is a link to my page in case you need to see what I'm talking about. It is the welcome bar on top of the page [Blog](http://tradingliberation.com)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you do know that your question has nothing to do the php, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
    <!--Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
    <div id="mc_embed_signup" style="display:none">
    <form action="http://tradingliberation.us6.list-manage2.com/subscribe/post?u=391b0d0328b13e63321867c4b&amp;id=9fce6d2cd6" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <label for="mce-EMAIL">Stay Connected & Take One Step Closer Towards Liberation</label>
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="enter email address..." required>
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
    </form>
    </div>
    <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```